# Julia | DataFrame conversion to JSON

Tags: json, dataframe, julia

I have a dataframe in Julia like df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M"]). I have to convert it into a JSON like

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "A": "1",
            "B": "M"
        },
        {
            "A": "2",
            "B": "F"
        },
        {
            "A": "3",
            "B": "F"
        },
        {
            "A": "4",
            "B": "M"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a method in DataFrames to do this. In a [github issue](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/issues/873) where the following snippet, using JSON.jl, is offered as a method to write json:

```
using JSON
using DataFrames

function df2json(df::DataFrame)
  len = length(df[:,1])
  indices = names(df)
  jsonarray = [Dict([string(index) => (isna(df[index][i])? nothing : df[index][i])
                     for index in indices])
               for i in 1:len]
  return JSON.json(jsonarray)
end

function writejson(path::String,df::DataFrame)
  open(path,"w") do f
    write(f,df2json(df))
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Andy for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

[JSONTables](https://github.com/JuliaData/JSONTables.jl) package provides JSON conversion to/from [Tables.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/Tables.jl)-compatible sources like `DataFrame`.

```
using DataFrames
using JSONTables

df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M"])

jsonstr = objecttable(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can simply use `JSON.json(df)`, which will create JSON of the form `{"col1": values, "col2": values}`